# What things can help keep stray dogs warm?

Tags: dogs, health, safety

It is cold in India. Stray dogs literally shake while sleeping. I do not have enough blankets for them. What other things can Insulate cold air? Can paper do it? If not, what other things can be used? Thank You Humans.

Comment: anything a dog can hide under will help.

Comment: @trondhansen there are cars but most of them dont prefer going near it because people just run over them.

Comment: i was thinking of someting like a box or some type of roof even an upsidedown boat or similar things,having something over your body will limit the cooling.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if you are rural or in a city, but dried plants can help as well. A lot of heat will be lost because they lay on cold ground, so a pile of leaves, straw or hay may already help a lot.
Cardboard-boxes can be a help, too: they insulate from the ground, and shelter from cold winds.
Paper would insulate, yes, but it has the annoying tendency to be blown away, so boxes and dried plant-stuff may be your better option.
In general, the biggest problems for heat-loss will be a cold ground and cold winds, so anything insulating the ground and sheltering from winds should already help!

Comment: I will try newspapers with stones. Cardboard boxes get stolen.

Comment: Can you describe the area you’re in? Different environments can have different solutions. I guessing urban? If you can describe or post a picture of the neighborhood where these dogs are, I will give suggestions for that specific location. You may be able to build some small hidden shelters around your area. As mentioned, leaves, hay, paper, cardboard are all good insulators. I hope to hear back so we can find solutions for the cold dogs!

Comment: @M.Mat Sorry, I am sorry I did not see your comment. The winter is over, thanks to climate change and global warming, but knowledge helps. I live in a city(urban). The dogs sleep in the streets and eat from garbage or wasted food. The pups live in isolated areas like empty grounds, homes where no one now lives, etc. I had put up a cardboard box for a litter of 13 pups, but it got stolen in a day. Where can I get dry leaves from? Thank you.

Comment: Dry leaves/plant materials, hay or straw, scraps of old clothing or clean rags, all will be insulation for them. I would check at a plant nursery—anyplace where they sell plants. They have lots of “waste” in the form of dead plants, etc. Check their bin. Can you build a small lean-to and prop it against a wall, fence or pile of junk? You can buy bags of cloth scraps very cheaply-at least you can here in the States.  Please don’t give up on them! Thanks